# Nginx - Lots of access and error logs with different domain names

Tags: nginx

I've setup Nginx for my domain example.com with access and error log enabled. But in Nginx log directory there is lots of log files generated with different domain names which does not related to my server or A record!

I've removed soft link of `default` file from `sites-enabled`

Nginx server setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate.key

    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log;

    # ...
}
```

In log directory `/var/log/nginx` there is lots of unwanted files are as:

```
bit.ly.access.log
dlvr.it.access.log
fb.me.access.log
goo.gl.access.log
httpheader.net.access.log
ift.tt.access.log
images.apple.com.access.log
is-work.appspot.com.access.log
ow.ly.access.log
snip.ly.access.log
testp1.piwo.pila.pl.access.log
twitter.com.access.log
virtuesshop.com.access.log
www.bmwblog.com.access.log
www.ctrip.com.access.log
www.google.com.access.log
Www.Peoplematters.in.access.log
xxnet-300.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-301.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-302.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-303.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-304.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-400.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-401.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-402.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-403.appspot.com.access.log
xxnet-404.appspot.com.access.log
z.cdn.turner.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-110.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-111.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-112.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-113.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-114.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-115.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-116.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-117.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-118.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-119.appspot.com.access.log
z-h-e-n-119.appspot.com.access.log.1
...
```

There are so many of files with different domains likes this!

Is it a security risk? How can I fix this problem and prevent such types of activity in future?

Answer (score 0):

You should add another block

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    listen 443 ssl default;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate.key;
    return 403 "Nothing here";
    access_log off;
}
```

What this will do is that it will listen to anything except `www.example.com` and return `403`. You can return `200` or anything else you want.

Comment: Without any server_name specified?

Comment: Yes, that will catch anything else other than `www.example.com`

Comment: Any idea why this happens? A Record has only set for example.com then how can others domain reach here!

Comment: `Host` header can easily be spoofed, that is what is happening here, you connect to IP but spoof the header. Mostly automated bots crawling IPs